# Xcode - Custom classes aren't working

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using Xcode in order to make a small app for myself and until now everything was working fine. But now I have a problem with my custom classes. I'm making new files and trying to set them as a custom class for a view controller, but Xcode ignores these new files and I can't choose them as a class. What might it be? How can I fix it?

It's important to say that this problem just started now. Also, I re-installed Xcode and it didn't help at all.

Thanks!

Comment: Are your custom classes subclasses of the appropriate class? E.g. a subclass of UITableViewController for a Table View Controller?

Comment: @MartinR Yes, I'm making a new file and its subclass is UIViewController.The new object is also UIViewController. So they are both UIViewControllers

Comment: It could help to re-create the issue using a simple stub (i.e. almost empty) project and post the code here.

Comment: Have you tried just typing in the custom subclass name into Interface Builder to replace the default UIViewController class ?

Comment: Alternately have you tried instantiating an instance of your subclass using [[YourSubclass alloc] initWithNIBName:bundle:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your new .m files are in the Compile Sources list of Build Phases.

- Click your project icon in the project navigator
- Click Build Phases
- Reveal Compile Sources.
- At the bottom, click the plus sign and then enter .m into the search bar. If any files are listed there, select them and add them.

I've had problems with new classes not appearing here in the past.

Comment: As specified above, make sure you're subclassing the proper class. It has to be one of those two things.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My custom class subclassed `UIViewController` and I was trying to set it as the class for a UI table view controller in Interface Builder. But none of my custom classes were available to select in the Identity Inspector, nor could I specify my module.

I resolved this issue by changing the subclass of my custom class to `UITableViewController`. That allowed me to set my class for the table view controller in the Identity Inspector, as well as specify my module.

Then I went back to the class and changed the subclass back to `UIViewController`. The table view controller in Interface Builder retained its connection to my custom class, as well as to the module.

Another solution, as others have said, would have been to leave my class as a subclass of `UITableViewController`.